# Can Ivy download multiple versions of the same dependency?

Tags: ivy

I am well aware of the fact that this is not good idea, but I need to define a dependency with multiple versions. I would also like to know if it is possible to resolve all transitive dependencies of such diamond dependencies. For example, if two dependencies of the project each have a dependency on `commons-lang` (`2.1` and `3.0`) and the project itself defines version `2.5`, I would like to be able to download all three versions along with their transitive dependencies. Is this at all possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, "yes", as shown below:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.foo"
          module="diamond-dependency"
          revision="1.0-SNAPSHOT"/>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="javax.activation" name="activation" rev="1.1-rev-1"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-email" rev="1.3.1"/>
        <conflict manager="all"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

The key bit is in the conflict manager section which, in this case, is being told to resolve all conflicting dependencies.

The above will have a dependency tree looking like this (containing three different versions of `javax.activation:activation`:

```
+- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-rev-1:compile 
\- org.apache.commons:commons-email:jar:1.3.1:compile 
   +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile 
   |  \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1-rev-1) 
   \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1-rev-1)
```

Comment: However, oddly, the `javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1` is not resolved.